# Text decoration line through css does not work on Safari with my "completed" class

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I have been testing my app on several devices and just found out that one of my css styles is not working on Safari, specifically my iPhone and iPad. I am making a to do app with Angular and would like a red line to cross out the text when the item is marked completed.

If I create a new paragraph element and give it the class **test** and apply the css below, the styling works fine.

Example, this line gets crossed out

```
<p class="test">testing 3</p>
```

With this css

```
.test {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  -webkit-text-decoration-line: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

However, this html does not get crossed out

```
  <li *ngFor="let list of lists" [class.completed]="list.completed" class="list-lines">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="check">
          <input id='checked' *ngIf="list.completed === false" type="checkbox" (click)='isChecked(list)'>
          <input id='checked' *ngIf="list.completed === true" type="checkbox" (click)='isChecked(list)' checked>
        </td>
        <td class="todoBox">
          <span class="todo" (click)="isChecked(list)">{{list.item}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="delOneButton" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delOne(list)" [hidden]="!list.completed">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
```

When this css is applied to my class **completed**. Like I said it works fine on my desktop with Chrome, but not on my Safari. What gives??

```
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  -webkit-text-decoration-line: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

I found this documentation but can't seem to find anything else about the mobile css syntax for line through text decoration. Does anyone know where I can find the syntax?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like I needed to be more specific with the webkit css. Instead of

```
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  -webkit-text-decoration-line: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

I needed to write

```
.completed .todoBox .todo {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  -webkit-text-decoration-line: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed this for ios chrome browser

Answer (score 4):

Here we go `-webkit-text-decoration-line: line-through;` more information about this you could read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-decoration-line). Hope this help :)

Comment: Aww had my hopes this was going to work. It didn't work. I don't know if it is because the mobile safari and desktop safari have different compatiblilty?? :(

Comment: Ok It does work. But not the way I am intending. Can you check my code and see what the problem is? I will add my html code and further explain.

Comment: everything is fine, works on my iphone too. see this fiddle and tell me what you see https://jsfiddle.net/nyrq2x8c/5/

Comment: Yes I can see the cross through. I revised my question since that works. Can you review it again and see if you can help me?

Comment: Try to styling to specific browser, safari: ` _::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .yourclass {}` safari bug i guess

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Safari and Google Chrome.

```
.test{
     text-decoration: line-through red;
     -webkit-text-decoration: line-through red;
```

}