# Google Optimize A/B Test Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ab-testing, google-optimize

I am currently building an A/B Test with Google Optimize that has 2 variants. The first variant displays perfectly fine on mobile/desktop and Chrome/Safari/Firefox. Variant 2 is a different story. There is supposed to be a red strikethrough line through the original price. The issue that arises is this:

- **Chrome/Firefox (desktop):** strikethrough renders
- **Safari (desktop):** no strikethrough appears
- **Chrome/Firefox/Safari (mobile):** no strikethrough appears

[Rendered Strikethrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnHE.png)
[Missing Strikethrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztepn.png)

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or have any idea what the issue may be? Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254417 for the win!!!

Comment: Please add the code you have used, so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254417 had the answer. needed to include **-webkit-** stylings as well.